# cleaned_data is returning wrong/different value

Tags: python, django

I have been struggling with the Forms in Django. Able to get the value from the cleaned_data but it returns a totally different number. For example, I have 4 values to choose from (2,3,4,5). If I select 2, it will give cleaned_data.get(name_of_form_field) returns 5. And so on.

```
class PopulationForm(forms.Form):
    districts = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Population.objects.order_by('districtid').values_list('districtid',flat=True).distinct())
```

There are 4 options for a user to choose from: 2,3,4,5. If the user selects 2, it returns 5 and so on. I am not sure what's happening.
 Here is my views.py:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PopulationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data.get('districts'))
            return HttpResponse(form.cleaned_data.get('districts'))
```

Here is my template:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Django Forms Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Django Forms Tutorial</h2>

<form action="/display/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{form.as_table}}

 </table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do *not* use `.values_list()`. A `ModelChoiceField` expects *model* objects.

Comment: Then, how do I get distinct values without using that?

Comment: well it looks like this is not a model, but some `CharField`, then you should use a `ChoiceField`, and determine the `choices` in the form constructor.

Comment: Population is a model that I am importing.

Comment: `Population` yes, but the `districts`? You here do not pick `Population` objects, you pcik values to fill in for `districts`.